# Мониторинг потребления трафика на linux python

Tags: python, linux, мониторинг, трафик

**Цель:** контролировать потребление прокси.

У меня есть код Python, который подключается к стороннему API через прокси.

Сложность в том, что скрипт многопоточный (потоки запускаются через multiprocessing.Process), у каждого потока есть ID. Мне нужно понять, сколько каждый поток потребляет прокси.

Пробовал сохранять PID для каждого потока и ловить трафик через linux nethogs, но данные неверны, часть пакетов теряется и трафик не сходится с реальным.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть более лаконичное решение для контроля расхода прокси?

Comment: Пусть потоки в базу пишут, потом соберёте из базы статистику да посмотрите. Сам то поток знает, сколько он данных отправил и принял или нет?

Comment: Нет, поток не знает и я не знаю как отловить. Запросы делаются через библиотеку (не через requests)

Comment: И нет возможности какими-то байтами померить сколько данных вернулось из `API`? Или там не очень соотносятся байты с реальным траффиком?

Comment: Перед тем как вернуть ответ, API может сделать несколько запросов и расходовать доп. трафик. Я думаю мне нужно их отслеживать сторонними методами (не внутри скрипта потока)

Comment: потребляет прокси - штук, байт, конектов, запросов?

Comment: @eri байт, кб, мб, очевидно

Comment: не сказал бы что очевидно. трафик сжатый учитывать? ssl считается ? с учетом операции коннект или без?